# Unable to open database for Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, sqlite

While Capture the Microsoft edge browser history it shows the error Unable to open database in this line (`connection.Open();`)...

```cs
string ME = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\WebCacheV01.dat";

SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + ME + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
connection.Open();
SQLiteDataAdapter sd = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + "Container_n", connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sd.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

connection.Close();
```

Comment: Post the actual error, not just parts of the message. Is the path wrong for example? Or is the database in use? SQLite is an embedded, single-user, file-based database though. You can't open a file exclusively opened for reading by another process, much less a SQLite database.

Comment: Ji....while I am trying to open the connection(i.e.,Connection.Open()) it shows error message like this : System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'unable to open database file'

Comment: Is Edge running? You can't open an already opened file, unless the process that. opened it specifically enabled sharing. Try using the `Read Only=True` parameter in the connection string. This could still fail though

Comment: No, I have closed the microsoft edge browser and After given read only = true in connection string also it gets the same error ji. System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'unable to open database file'

Comment: Thanks ji.....I got the output..:)